# Python: How (can) I store a "return" or "break" in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, return, break

```
    select = input("Enter what you would like to do (enter 'x' to exit): ")
    functions = {"c": calculator, "a": addsubtract, "s": squareroot,
                 "p": power, "n": arrange, "f": factorial} # storing break or return result in "Invalid Syntax" in the dictionary 
    #currently I'm doing this: 
    if select != "x":
        functions[select]()
    else:
        return
```

I'm trying to minimize code and have been able to do so by storing functions in a dictionary; I'd like to know if there was a workaround/similar way of doing this in case it's not possible using a dictionary.

Comment: No you cannot. `return` and `break` are statements.

Comment: So there's no workaround? (I'm not obsessed with making code smaller, but it would be nice if half the function wasn't just testing for an exit if you know what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

You can't:

```
def r():
    return 1

def print_hello():
    print("HelloWorld")

l = [print_hello, print_hello, print_hello, r, None]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        print(i, end='')
        l[i]()

$ python3 test.py
> 0HelloWorld
> 1HelloWorld
> 2HelloWorld
> 34Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
>   l[i]()
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

And it is not a good idea to store functions in a dictionary:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

> Flat is better than nested.

Comment: Why would that not be a good idea? Can lead to terrific patterns if you know what you are doing :)

Comment: If you keep your code small and you are the only one using it, why not. But otherwise, you can end up with nested blobs that will become unreadable and ugly.

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but what exactly does *Flat is better than nested.* mean?

Comment: Wait, and I *shouldn't* put functions in a dictionary? What'll happen if they got out of hand? I'm not going to be putting anything except the functions in that dictionary just to let you know. (I originially did it cuz I had half a screen of code with just 'if' statements testing if the user input was "a" go to etc. But if it's programming practice, I'll try thinking of another way.

Comment: This problem comes form the user `input` that forces you to make a `case` (either lot of `if`, either functions in a dictionary). The use on `input` disappear quickly as the program grows and end up on thing like graphical inputs...

Comment: @NeelKamath when you end up with things like `a(b[c(e+f).g()](h))` you are not in the right direction. Flatten things, even if you end up with more lines. If you don't like it, make objects; they are marvelous.

Comment: @PaulHOCHON oh, like that, ik to make it *flat.* But I felt for this when it's rather simple, yet a large numbers of functions, it'd be DRYer to use a dictionary

Comment: @PaulHOCHON and by object, if you mean a function or something, that's what I was doing (having all my functions and then one functions which only asks the user which function to access). Sorry, I just recently started learning classes and stuff.